# ¿ A que se debe este error en consola con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy ejecutando un asincronismo en js con es6 pero a la hora de implementarlo el browser en la consola me aparece un error como el siguiente:

```
TypeError: (0 , _translate2.default) is not a function(…)
```

a que se debe este error, porque aparece?

Comment: Que intentas ejecutar podrías poner un poco mas de código que lo intentas poner a correr?

Comment: Creo que quiere decir que `_translate2.default` no es una función...

Answer (score 1):

Como podrás leer en la [Red de Desarrolladores de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/TypeError), este fue creado para indicarte que el tipo de objeto que retornas no es el que se esperaba, en tu caso, posiblemente estabas programando un closure sin regresar una función.

por ejemplo:

```
var sumar= (function () {
    var suma = 0;
    return function () {return suma+= 1;}
})();
sumar();
```

y para que te de el error:

```
var sumar= (function () {
        var suma = 0;
        var hola = function () {return suma+= 1;}
    })();
sumar();
```